# how to skip brackets with scanf

Tags: c

thanks for your help... but still it doesn't print out 300,400 on the screen. below is my fullcode:  reads a file[file contain: S(300,400)] passed at commandprompt                         and reads the two values contained in it without printing or reading the S, the 1st bracket, the comma or the last closing bracket

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a;
int b;
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

    if ( argc != 2 ) /* argc should be 2 for correct execution */
    {
        /* We print argv[0] assuming it is the program name */
        printf( "usage: %s filename", argv[0] );
    }
    else 
    {
        // We assume argv[1] is a filename to open
        FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

        /* fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure */
        if ( file == 0 )
        {
            printf( "Could not open file\n" );
        }
        else 
        {
           /*reading file..
             while (fscanf(file, "S(%d,%d)", &a, &b) == 2)
            {
               printf("%d,%d", a, b);
            }


            fclose( file );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it too complicated. Just include the non-numerical parts literally:

```
while(fscanf(file, "S(%d,%d)", &a, &b) == 2)
  printf("got S(%d,%d)\n", a, b);
```

Also, note that `printf()` doesn't support patterns, that doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: thanks for your help... but still it doesn't print out 300,400 on the screen. below is my full code:

Answer (score 2):

There is no requirement for scan sets, just use:

```
while (2 == fscanf(file, "S(%d,%d)", &a, &b))
{
    printf("%d %d", a, b);
}
```

Compare `2` against the return value of `fscanf()` as the posted code could read just one integer (with `fscanf()` populating `a` only and returning `1`) but incorrectly use both `a` and `b`.

Comment: I am surprised by your yoda comparison.

Comment: @E_net4, just habit of always putting literals on the left (which are not modifiable).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a utility for parsing and checking regular expressions. Here is one online: [http://www.regextester.com/](http://www.regextester.com)

There are many others...